# OWL Carousel jQuery code is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very much new user of jQuery. I am facing this problem in the html code. The code are gray color and not working in the site. Can any one help me please? Here is the code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".our-team").owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
        itemsDesktopSmall : [970, 4],
        theme:"team-slider-theme",
    });

});
```

```html
<div class="our-team"> 
                    <div class="single-member">
                        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
                        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-member">
                        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
                        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="single-member">
                        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
                        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="single-member">
                        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
                        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in your browser?

Comment: <div class="section-tiltle">
<div class="our-team owl-carousel team-slider-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
<div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: none;">
<div class="owl-pagination">
<div class="owl-page active">
<span class=""></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>     From <div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: none;">  to end of the dive is gray colored, probable not working the codes.

Comment: Looks good in **[this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ekt27jjb/1/)**.. You sure that you have included all the required files?

Comment: I think I have included all the files correctly.

Comment: Please confirm it once again.. Check for any console errors in your browser in the first instance..

Comment: how can i show you? I am trying to fix it for about 5 hours but not yet solved.

Comment: Add class item to `<div class="single-member"> `

Comment: Are you using owl version 1 or 2?

Comment: Also did you include jquery before owl scripts

Comment: I am using version 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out its working http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/50/. I just tested your code, you didn't include everything properly.

HTML

```
<div class="our-team"> 
    <div class="single-member item">
        <img  src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="single-member item">
        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="single-member item">
        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
    </div>   
    <div class="single-member item">
        <img src="img/member-face.png" alt="">
        <h3>Jason Statham<span>Knife designer </span></h3>
        <p>Do not seek to change what has come before. Seek to create that which has not.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".our-team").owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    itemsDesktopSmall : [970, 4],
    theme:"team-slider-theme",
});

});
```

**EDIT**

In head before your main style include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

In footer include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/yourMainJsFileWhereYourJsCodeIs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks . Now it is working . But when I include 4 items it is not working . Have any suggestion about how can I include the 4 items in the corousel.

Comment: yes I wanted like that :) thanks again. But what was the problem in my coding. I am very new user of Jquery (don't mind)

Comment: I don't mind and i am not sure, i don't see your full code. If this helped you, accept the answer.